# Advantage Database Server ignores Index

Tags: advantage-database-server

I've a problem where ADS seems to ignore an index. We have a big solution written in Visual Foxpro 9.0 which works with a VFP-Database (DBF and CDX). We want to use ADS for new extention written in DotNet. Both the old VFP-App and the new one should work side by side on the same database.
The problem is that ADS ignores the indexes in the CDX-Files in all select statements which results in a horrible performance.
Environment: ADS 12.0.0.0 (also tested in 11.10.0.22)

For a test I created an Testtable in VFP with the command

```
set collate to "MACHINE"
create table D:\Temp\TestADS\test (F1 C(10), F2 C(100))
index on F1 tag F1
for lnx = 1 to 1000000
    insert into test (F1, F2) values (transform(lnx), "the quick brown fox jumps ... "
endfor
```

I then used Advantage Data Architect, created a connection to the testfolder (local server, TableType:VFP, LockingMode:compatible, collation:machine_vfp_bin_1252) and used the SQL-Utility with the following query:

```
select  F1, F2 from test where F1 = '1000'
```

The query took 420 ms and the Execution Plan says it is using an "Table Scan" with the warning:

```
Restriction is not optimized.
Unoptimized Part : F1="1000"
```

I then use Advantage Data Architect, open the table and select "Re-Index".
Now the same query tooks 4 ms and the Execution Plan says "AOF Scan" without any warning.

It seems, that ADS ignores the index as long as it is not created by himself. If I fire a reindex in VFP the query is unoptimized again...

Can someone give me a hint or is it a bug?

By the way, login in the forum at http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/account/signin/ dosn't work, internal server error :-(

Comment: You can use http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/account/tempsignin/ to get a temporary sign in link.